# Why isn't this circle rotating around the correct center?

Tags: javascript, animation, geometry, trigonometry

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yJJs7/

Javascript:

```
function main(){
    var centerx=250;
    var centery=250;
    var degrees=0;
    var div=document.getElementById('test');
    var move=function(){    
        if(degrees>360)degrees=degrees%360;
        var radians = degrees*Math.PI/180;
        var newx = Math.cos(radians)*100;
        var newy = Math.sin(radians)*100;
        div.style.top=(newy+centery)+'px';
        div.style.left=(newx+centerx)+'px';
        degrees+=10;   
    };
    setInterval(move,50);
    console.log(div);
}
main();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:black;
    border-radius:100px;
    position:fixed;
}
#test2{
    position:fixed;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:black;
    border-radius:30px;
    position:fixed;
    top:250px;
    left:250px;
}
```

​

The second div is centered at 250x250 px, and the first div should rotate around it. Why isn't it?

​

Comment: +1 for a interesting question:-) plain JS 2D animation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equation is calculating the new position for the centre of the circle, but style.top/style.left goes from the top/left-most points on the circle, you need to subtract the radius:

```
div.style.top=(ny+cy-35)+'px';
div.style.left=(nx+cx-35)+'px';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yJJs7/1/

---

That will be rotating around the centre of the small circle (265, 265) rather than (250, 250) though, so you probably want to offset the small circle in the css:

```
#test2{
    ...
    top:235px;
    left:235px;
}

div.style.top=(ny+cy-50)+'px';
div.style.left=(nx+cx-50)+'px';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yJJs7/7/

Comment: Brilliant, that was a terrible miss.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    #test {
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        background:black;
        border-radius:100px;
        position:fixed;
    }
    #test2 {
        position:fixed;
        height:30px;
        width:30px;
        background:black;
        border-radius:30px;
        position:fixed;
        top:250px;
        left:250px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        main(100);
    });

    function main(distance) {

        var $this = $("#test2");
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var width = $this.width();
        var height = $this.height();

        var cx = offset.left + width / 2;
        var cy = offset.top + height / 2;

        var i = 0;
        var $div = $('#test');
        var divOffset = $div.offset();
        var divWidth = $div.width();
        var divHeight = $div.height();

        var move = function () {
            if (i > 360) i = i % 360;
            var j = i * Math.PI / 180;
            var nx = Math.cos(j) * distance;
            var ny = Math.sin(j) * distance;
            var left = nx + cx - divWidth / 2
            var top = ny + cy - divHeight / 2

            $div.offset({
                top: top,
                left: left
            });

            i += 10;
        };

        setInterval(move, 50);

    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="test2"></div>
</body>
```